# SharePoint 2019 SPFx solution deployment issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, spfx-webparts, error, 2019

I am having trouble in installing Apps on a particular site collection, getting a message (`SkipFeatureDeployment:false`):

> "You can't add app here" contact the administrator.

But the same apps are working when I am deploying them with `SkipFeatureDeployment` to `true` and making them available to all sites upon deployment in app catalog.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Do you have site collection administrator permissions on the site collection? Try using account with SCA permissions. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Yes I am SCA , when I click the Find out Why link it is showing me a message "Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server. tell them to enable apps"

Comment: Are you using tenant level app catalog or site collection level app catalog? Try this once: https://natechamberlain.com/2020/10/19/sharepoint-2019-solution-sorry-apps-are-turned-off-if-you-know-who-runs-the-server-tell-them-to-enable-apps/

Comment: I am using Site collection level app catalog

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue by adding appurl and appdomain

App Url was not configured => Chances are you have not configured the App Urls. Please ensure you have given values to App Domain and App Prefix in your App Store settings.